# JavaScript parse function JSON.parse does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, json

The case:

```
var s = '{"a": 2}';
var d = JSON.parse(s); // d = Object {a: 2}
```

It is OK.

The similar case does not parse string, however. Why?

```
var s = "{'a': 2}";

var d= JSON.parse(s) // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

Expected result - parsed object like in the first case. It should have worked because ' and " are interchangeable in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [standard](http://json.org/), you need double quotes to denotes a string, which a key is.

Answer (score 2):

> It should have worked because ' and " are interchangeable in javascript.

JSON is not JavaScript.

JSON strings must be delimited with quotation marks, not apostrophes.

See [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7):

> A string begins and ends with quotation marks.

Comment: `delimited` is not the apt word for it. I guess it should be, `keys should be wrapped in double quotes`.